# Angular: routing resolver placement

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module, angular-resolver

Does it matter where the `resolver` exists in Angular in these two examples? Both of these two snippets of code achieve the same result:

**Placing the resolver at the module-level within `AppModule`:**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'user',
    resolve: {
      user: UserResolver
    },
    loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)
  },
];
```

**vs. placing it directly on the component (with children routes) for the routing defined inside the `UserModule`:**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
    resolve: {
      user: UserResolver
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'details',
        component: DetailsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'change-password',
        component: ChangePasswordComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

What is the difference between resolving the data at the module level, vs. resolving it at the component level, with `children` routes?

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding of it :

On the module level, the resolve will only run when the module is accessed/loaded, and As for the component level whichever component you put your resolve on will work.